# Set Unions and Intersections proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone help me how to do this, like there are some examples in my book, but this exercise problem seems to be alittle difficult for me to approach:

Given a set $\{A_k|k\in\mathbb{N}\}$:
$$A_k=\bigg\{x\in\mathbb{R}\bigg|\space\space 1-\frac{1}{k}<x<1+\frac{1}{k}\bigg\}$$

Find:
$$\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k,\text{and} \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k$$

**My thoughts:**

I think that $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k=(0,2)$, since the range of the inequality gets smaller from $(0,2)$ to $(0.5,1.5), (0.666, 1.3333)$ etc.. However I have trouble showing this in a mathematical way. Can anyone provide me with some assistance as I am having trouble with reasoning with set logic.

Additionally for $\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k$, eventually as $k\rightarrow \infty$ then the inequaliy becomes $1<x<1$, which does not make sense and thus the intersections must be $\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}} A_k =\emptyset$?

Comment: Your reasoning is right (assuming $\mathbb{N}$ starts from 1). To prove it mathematically, note that $x \in \bigcup A_k$ iff $x \in A_k$ for *some* $k$, and $x \in \bigcap A_k$ iff $x \in A_k$ for *all* $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A_1=(0,2)$ and since $k\geqslant1\implies A_k\subset(0,2)$, the union $\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}A_k$ is indeed $(0,2)$.

And the intersection $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_k$ is $\{x\}$, because:

- $x\in A_k$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$;
- if $y\ne x$, then $y>x+\frac1k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$ or $y<x-\frac1k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$. In both case, $y\notin A_k$ and therefore $y\notin\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_k$.

Comment: I am sorry I still quite do not understand the arguments for intersection, could you kindly elaborate alittle further to your arguments?

Comment: Asserting that $y\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_k$ is *the same thing* as asserting that $y$ belongs to *every* $A_k$. So, asserting that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_k=\{x\}$ is the same thing as asserting that $x$ belongs to every $A_k$ and that, if $y\ne x$, then there is some $k$ such that $y$ does *not* belong to $A_k$. And that is what I proved.

Comment: Thank you, but what I dont understand is why do we have to show that there is some $y$ which does not belong to some $A_k?$

Comment: Where did I do that?

Comment: Like at the end of your asnwer,  $y\notin A_k$, $y\notin\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_k$ I do not get this implication.

Comment: At the end of my answer I proved that, for *every* $y\ne x$ (not just *some* $y$), there is some $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $y\notin A_k$. Since $y$ does not belong to some $A_k$ and since $\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}A_k$ is the set of those real numbers which belong to *every* $A_k$, $y\notin\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}A_k$.

Comment: Nevermind I think I get it now thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: May I additionally ask how did you get the expressions for the lower and upper bounds for $y$?

Comment: But what is $x$? In the question, it was only used as a parameter to define the set $A_k$, right?

Comment: @BlackMamba No; $x$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that $\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N} A_k = (0,2)$, then you have to prove two things:

- If $x\in \bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N} A_k$, then $x\in (0,2)$. In other words, if $x\in A_k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, then $x\in (0,2)$.
- If $x\in (0,2)$, then $x\in \bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N} A_k$. In other words, if $x\in (0,2)$, then $x\in A_k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

The first item should be easy, and the second item not too bad.

A similar structure would hold for $\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N} A_k$ (where each "for some $k\in\Bbb N$" would be replaced by "for all $k\in\Bbb N$"). But be warned: $\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N} A_k$ is not empty!